# Using rendered facebook name in title of created Event

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to have a facebook rendered name used in the title or any field of a created event?

when I place

```
$name="Welcome to a <fb:name uid=\"$friend1\" /> Event";
```

in the event array,

```
$event_param = array(
"access_token" => $params['access_token'],
"name" => $name,
"start_time" => $nextWeek,
"location" => $place
);
```

the created event is literally titled:

Welcome to a fb:name uid=\"100089XXXXXXX" / Event

i can't  put on the < > around the fb tag in this forum because it won't show up, but you get the idea

Answer (score 1):

No this isn't possible, the event name is static and doesn't parse the old FBML tags. Assuming you already have an access token for the user (which you probably do if you want to post a new event) you could just pull the user's name from the API and use that directly